# Android (Java) - Get the private numbers that calls you

Tags: java, android, phone-number

I'm developing a simple app that shows the number of private-caller

Although I searched a lot on internet, i found only one code that i guess i won't work.

Code is this.

```
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
         if(null == bundle)
                 return;
         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());
         String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);            
         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);
         if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
         {
             phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
             Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incoming Number: " + phonenumber);      
         }
```

and for the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

lets's android devs please help me to solve the problem.

PS: Those who dont know what is private number - it is number that you can't see for example code is + 1 234 456 but you see onle the text Private Number.

Comment: So what's going on with this code that you've found?

Comment: What makes you think that a private number is even being sent to the phone? That would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I just tried the code again nothing happened,state is null i guess...